# Control user access to the internet via MS Internet Security & Acceleration Server

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, enterprise-library

I want to allow / disallow a user from using internet(via Internet Security and Acceleration Server) and restrict or allow some softwares like Outlook. I am developing a windows service in c#. I came to know that i can do it by using .NET enterprise server.

I tried my best to search an example on internet or some refference material but no luck. I am still searching. If anyone has idea about such things then please guide me or suggest helping materials. I have to implement it ASAP.